# run pydev project from file-system (with imports from different packages)

Tags: eclipse, filesystems, pydev, package

I want to run my **working** pydev project python code by double clicking the main module (outside of eclipse): xxx.py

The problem is that due to my imports being in different packages:

```
from src.apackage.amodule import obj
```

when xxx.py is double clicked it complains it doesn't know where the imports are (even though when I run xxx.py in pydev it *magically* knows what I'm importing).

A simple workaround is to remove all of the packages and move all of the modules into one directory (that obviously works but is very inconvenient)

How can I run my code in the file system without doing that work around?

Comment: I found another way: using pthyon setup.py install creates a distribution version of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page answers my question excellently:

http://blog.habnab.it/blog/2013/07/21/python-packages-and-you/

Bottom line is always execute your code from the top, highest level, root directory (e.g. using a minimal **main**.py file that executes the main script of your program). Then, use absolute imports always and you never have a missing module issue since you start the program from the top directory and all imports are based off that 'home' path.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you encountered is the natural behavior of most languages. A programm only knows about its working path (the path it is started in), the paths which are registered in the environment variables and at least relative paths.

The "magic" of the executable you created is therefore: It collects all scripts/modules needed, and copies/combines them next to/in the executable. The Executable then runs within the directory where all other scripts also reside and voila ...

If you are not happy with your workaround of creating an executable every time you want to run your project without PyDev there are two alternatives.
First but not the one I would suggest is registering the working path into in the environment variables.
Second and the one I think is much better: Create a link to the python executable and alter the calling string of the textfield "Target:". Append the path to your script you would like to run. Then alter the textfield "Start in:" and enter the project directory. After you did this you should be able to start your project with a simple double click.

(If you rely on external libraries which are neither on the path nor in you project you could search for appending paths temporarily to the pythonpath via the sys module.)

I hope I could help a bit.

Comment: Just a couple notes for clarification: when I used "python setup.py install" it didn't make an executable - it installs the modules into the python lib directory so it knows where they are. Had I installed py2exe and performed a py2exe command then it would have been an executable. In any case, using your method still resulted in the same problem (it didn't know where any of the modules were - and even the ones in the same package since the "start in" was no longer the same folder as the main module being executed).

Comment: my imports stem from the "src" folder (which contains all of the packages). I made my "start in" just before the src folder (the main program folder) and I also tried making it the src folder itself. Precisely the same error of not finding the modules occurred in either "start in" case.

Comment: Well then I'm sorry but I can't help.